# LAST_INSERT_ID() in the same request

Tags: mysql

Is that possible to add a new entry, copy its ID (auto incremented) and add it in the entry's column. Example of what I am looking for:

```
INSERT INTO `my_stuff` (title`, `description`, `this_entry_ID`) VALUES ('$my_stuff', '$description', LAST_INSERT_ID())");
```

Right now, I do it using two requests:

1. add a new entry and copy the new entry's ID (using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`)
2. Update the entry with the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` data.

Is this possible to do it all in one go?

Note: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is used for reference only to describe what I need.

Comment: If I read your question correctly, you're trying to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` as a reference column to the primary key of the current row (much like `update my_stuff set reference_column = id_column`)? If this is right... why?

Comment: emm... that would be quite hard to explain. in brief - there is a chain of IDs (root/paret_id_1, parent_id_2,..., last_id (the one that is set after the new entry is added ). Kinda weird but, believe, me it makes sense.
(thank you for the edit and sorry for making those misspells )

Comment: "Kinda weird but, believe, me it makes sense" --- elaborate more please. It doesn't sound like it makes sense

Comment: I have provided you with all the required information. I need to know how and it doesn't matter why. Here is more info :

Database consists of the following columns:
1. ID (a.i. - let's say it's "42")
2. name
3. parent
4. chain

I need to insert (or APPEND) the ID to the CHAIN 
the chain consists of several IDs and typical entry looks like this "0/22/16" where all three numbers are lined up IDs that form a certain path. the last in such chain is supposed to be the ID of the entry (the "42").

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a sub-query that uses the target table in the insert.

```
insert into TheTable (Name, LastID) values ("New 1", (select Id from TheTable order by Id DESC limit 1) );
```

But you should not get an error doing what you suggested.

```
insert into TheTable (Name, LastID) values ("New 1", LAST_INSERT_ID() );
```

Comment: This will add a record with the same ID as last but not a newer one

Answer (score 1):

you can write a `TRIGGER` which acts immediately `AFTER INSERT` to update its `this_entry_ID` column.

Comment: yes yes...such thing is possible. I just wanted to find put whether it's possible to make all using one request without any extra things. But - thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` works for the duration of the connect, so if you use the same connection for both queries, it will work.

If your connection library supports multiple commands per request, you can simply separate the two queries with a semicolon and make one database call.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... thanks all, it appears that I've managed to solve this. Once again - the task was weird so the solution is quite weird too. Maybe you could offer anything better Here it is:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT  INTO @stuff FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'gallery_albums';

INSERT INTO `gallery_albums` (`album_title`, `album_description`, `parent_id`,  `created_at`, `views`, `added_by`, `chain`) VALUES ('xxx', 'cccc', '0', 'vvvv', '0', 'bbb', @stuff)
```